# "Please come to me" or "Please come here" or "Please come to my desk."

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases, politeness, transitivity, imperative-sentences

In my workplace many of my colleague are using the phrase "Please come to me" is that a correct a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it might be a colloquial way of speaking. It is not technically incorrect, but stylistically might sound incorrect.

Please come over
Please meet me
Please come over and see me
Please see me at my desk
Please see me in my office

Answer (score 0):

However you can say Please come to me if.... (eg you have any problems, you want a pay rise etc.). That however is giving permission to seek my advice or ask me for a rise. Maybe that is what you heard.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Chris. Is this supposed to be a complete answer to the question, or a comment on somebody else's answer? Normally, you use **however** to link two clauses together, not to start a sentence, for example "It is raining today, however I shall go to the park anyway".